# How would I return 165 from the attached class

Tags: javascript, html, return-value, children, getelementsbyclassname

I haven't touched JavaScript in a while and thought since the Olympics are on currently, I could use the opportunity to play around with returning countries with at least 1 medal, etc. I am trying to find out, through Javascript, how many countries at the moment have got at least 1 medal in the Commonwealth Games. I am stuck at a point of getting the value from the class. To get to this point, on the tenplay.com.au website I have gone into the console and done:

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName("medal-tally")[0].children[1].children[0];
check.getElementsByClassName("total");
```

This returns:

```
<td class=​"total" title=​"Total">​165​</td>
```

This is probably very very simple, but I have failed so far. I have tried `.value`, `.className`, checking if it returns true with == 165 and === "165", I believe these are all valid but I am a bit rusty as you can tell.

Thank you in advance for the help,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) return an array like object. You can use index to fetch its element then  You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) property

Use

```
var text = check.getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, easy as haha... need to do more JavaScripting, it is too fun ;)

Comment: @DanielJochem Side note: `getElementsByClassName` isn't as well-supported as `querySelectorAll` (IE8 has the latter, and not the former), so it's usually best to use the latter: `var text = check.querySelectorAll(".total")[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: This is for my own use, in Chrome, but this is good information for future reference, thanks @T.J.Crowder